# How do I place multiple dygraphs on one page

Tags: r, dygraphs

My goal is to place multiple dygraphs on one page in R so that I can use the "group" function to look at the data.

Is there a way to do this?

```
A_xts <- xts(test3$COL2,order.by=test3$Date)
B_xts <- xts(test$COL2,order.by=test$Date)

stocks <- cbind(A_xts,B_xts)
head(stocks)
testing<-dygraph(stocks, 
        main="Title") %>%
  dySeries("..1",label="LAB1") %>%
  dySeries("..2",label="LAB2") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = FALSE,colors=c("blue","brown")) %>%
  dyRangeSelector()
```

So I want to use this code for multiple data sets but add the "group" function to link all these dygraphs together? Any help would be great, thanks!